# Como resolver el error en Express.js usando multer y blackbaze b2:"message": "The \"url\" argument must be of type string. Received undefined"

Tags: javascript, mongoose, multer, express.js

A la hora de enviar una peticion a esa ruta me da el siguiente resultado
{
"message": "The "url" argument must be of type string. Received undefined"
}
Estoy intentando enviar unos datos en json y al mismo tiempo subir una imagen que esta se guarda en backblaze b2 y se sube mediante multer, y el link de la imagen guardarse como un String
Este es el controller:

```
export const createPlate = async (req,res) =>{
  try {
    // Confg b2 
   const b2 = new B2({
     applicationKeyId: process.env.KEY_ID,
     applicationKey: process.env.APP_KEY,       
   });

   b2.authorize().then(() => {
     console.log('Conexión exitosa a B2 Backblaze.');
   }).catch((err) => {
     console.error('Error al conectar a B2 Backblaze:', err);
   });
   


   const {name,description,price,disponibility} = req.body;

   const img = req.file.buffer;
   const fileName = req.file.originalname;

     // Subir la imagen a B2 Backblaze
     const response = await b2.uploadFile({
       fileName: fileName,
       data: img,
       bucketId: process.env.BUCKET_ID, // Cambiar por tu ID de bucket
     });
     console.log(response)
     const imageUrl = await b2.getDownloadURL(response.data.fileName); // Obtener la URL de descarga de la imagen
     console.log(imageUrl)
     const newPlate = new Plate({
       name,
       description,
       price,
       disponibility,
       img:imageUrl     
     });
     
     if (!name || !description || !price || !disponibility) {
       return res.status(400).send({
         error: 'Faltan datos.',
       });
     }

   const plateSaved = await newPlate.save()               
   res.status(201).json(plateSaved)
   } catch (error) {
     res.status(400).json({ message: error.message });
   }
  
}
```

y Asi es la ruta:

````
import * as platesController from "../controllers/plates.controller";
import { authJwt } from "../middlewares";
import multer from 'multer';

const router = Router();
const upload = multer({ storage:multer.memoryStorage() });

// Rutas de Platos
router.post('/', upload.single('img'), platesController.createPlate) ```
````

Comment: hola primero que nada te recomiendo que hagas el [tour], segundo segun el error que respotas, parace que el dato que estas pasando que debe ser un string llega otra cosa... verifica y valida que esta llegando, y de paso valida en que punto del codigo se esta rompiendo antes de llegar a donde sale el error...